# Using regex to go back to first occurence of character or string

Tags: regex

How do I make a match in a string to very first occurence of a character in a multi line file for example if i  have

---

$3.95
(html tags)
$2.95

(html tags)
(html tags)
Red door

### (html tags)

I want to just extract

---

$2.95

(html tags)
(html tags)

### Red door

So i want it to stop at the previous `$`, i tried something like `\$[\s\S]*Red door`, however that goes too far back, some asked for more specifics..

So here is a page on amazon, I want to pull out just the section sold and shipped by amazon:  http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00XR5HRBU/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new, I can easily go to alt="Amazon.com and then back up to the first $ which would do this.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for the job - use html parser!

Comment: Show the exact html codes. There's nothing we can do for you, if the code is this vague.

Comment: I need to use regex.  http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00XR5HRBU/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new  for example I want to pull out the section with just amazon has sold and shipped by them, so i can get the price, etc.

Comment: That's all findable with a parser. The first entry on the page you cite that is run by amazon has `<div class="a-row a-spacing-mini olpOffer">
                            <div class="a-column a-span2"><span class="a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold">            $259.00            </span>....

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags for why you shouldn't use `regex` to parse `html`. (It's because pretty fundamentally - the 'scope' of what regex can handle is smaller than the scope of what can be expressed in HTML)

Comment: I can not go into the reasons why html parsing would not work for this, but there are reasons why its not a good solution in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

A better tool for the job would be an HTML parser. But if you must, you can try to just not match another $ in the middle:

```
\$[^$]*Red door
```

Comment: While that does seem to work it makes me realize I actually need to go back to the following string olpOfferPrice a-text-bold">            $ is it possible to do that with first occurrence?